Extract a union of nested keys from an interface
I'm trying to get a union type made out of keys that are nested within the 'indexes' like in the code below.
interface DB {
  [key: string]: {
    indexes?: {
      [key: string]: any
    }
  }
}

interface MyDB extends DB {
  folders: {
    indexes: {
      'by-parent': string
    }
  }
  content: {
    indexes: {
      'by-title': string
    }
  }
}

type getAllIndexes<T extends DB> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]['indexes'] extends null ? never : keyof T[K]['indexes']
}[keyof T]

// expected behaviour: no error, the type should be equal to "by-title"|"by-parent"
// actual behaviour: Error - "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'."
const index: getAllInicies<MyDB> =  'by-parent'

When i alter the code a little bit to:
type getAllIndexes<T extends DB> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]['indexes'] extends null ? never : keyof T['folders']['indexes']
}[keyof T]

I'm suddenly getting back a literal type: "by-parent". So I think that the error lays in there.

Why interface MyDB extends DB { instead of just interface MyDB {? Is there a reason you want MyDB to have those index signatures? … You can still do it with the index signatures but you need to play games to exclude them when mapping over them. I’ll write up an example when I get off mobile.

• What is the point of your extends null check? The indexes property is either going to be some object or undefined, or possibly any; it should never be null. What does null have to do with the question? Please [edit] to address this. • See this playground link. That gives the two approaches; the first, where you don't try to include index signatures in MyDB, is much easier. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! I'm using an external library. I simplified the interface from this library to the form of the DB interface for the sake of this post and hence the index signatures.
As for the extends null check, well, that's a mistake on my part. I meant extends undefined. I was using PHP so much lately that I forgot about the undefined type in JS lol. Thank you for pointing it out too

But why a conditional check at all? What's wrong with just keyof T[K]['indexes']? If indices is missing then T[K]['indices'] will be unknown, not undefined, and then keyof will give never. Have you tested this part of it at all? I think we should separate the question into two pieces: one is whatever you're trying to do in your conditional check, and the other is the fact that index signatures "wash away" the type you care about... and then we should [edit] so that the question is about just one of these pieces. So, which stays, the index signatures or the conditional check?
